# Tkinter label font size interfere with the frame structure below

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a window with two main frames. One frame in row=0 called frame-A is used for a Title. The other frame in row=1 called frame-B is structured in several sub-frames with data. This frame-B has a label at the top (row = 0). It contains also several sub-frames in rows 1-3. If I use a font size of 15 for the label on frame-B, there are no problems. If I increase  the font size= 20, the sub-frames in the frame-B become separated. I am trying to understand how the font size is creating problems with the frames in rows 1-3.
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1200x1200")
#1-Main text
fr_A = tk.Frame(window,width=50, height=50, bd= 1,highlightbackground="green", highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=1)
tk.Label(fr_A,text="My title",font=("Courier", 30,"bold")).grid(row=0)
fr_A.grid(row=0)
#2-initial configuration  
fr_B = tk.Frame(window,width=300, height=300, bd= 1,highlightbackground="red",highlightcolor="red", highlightthickness=1)
fr_B.grid(row=1,column=0,ipady=80)
tk.Label(fr_B,text="Init data",font="helvetica 20",height=2).grid(row=0,column=0) #>>>>>>>font size problem
fr_list = []
for cr in ((1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2)):
    frame_in=tk.Frame(fr_B, highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1,bd= 1)
    frame_in.grid(row=cr[0],column=cr[1])
    fr_list.append(frame_in)
cnt = -1    
for fr in fr_list:
    for cr in ((0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)):
        cnt += 1
        tk.Label(fr,text=cnt,width=3,height =1).grid(row=cr[0],column=cr[1],sticky="nsew")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add columnspan to the title label.

tk.Label(fr_B, text="Init data",font="helvetica 20",height=2).grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=3) #>>>>>>>font size problem